# Adjusting data in a dictionary and then plotting it

Tags: python, pandas

I have

```
x = collections.Counter(df.f.values.tolist())
if 'nan' in x:
    del x['nan']
plt.bar(range(len(x)), x.values(), align='center')
plt.xticks(range(len(x)), list(x.keys()))

plt.show()
```

[image]

My question is, how can I remove the nan's from the dictionary that is created, and how can I change the order of the bar plot to go from 1-5? The first 3 nan's are empty spots in the data (intentional since its from a poll), and the last one is the title of the column. I tried manually changing the range part of plt.bar to be 1-5 but it does not seem to work.

Comment: I have tried: `clean_dict = filter(lambda k: not isnan(k), x)` but I don't think I implemented it correctly.

Comment: Why not simply use `df.f.value_counts().sort_index().to_frame().plot(kind='bar')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.value_counts` on a `pandas.Series` to simply get how many times each value occurs. This makes it simple to then make a barplot.

By default, `value_counts` will ignore the `NaN` values, so that takes care of that, and by using `.sort_index()` we can guarantee the values are plotted in order. It seems we need to use `.to_frame()` so that it only plots one color for the column (it chooses one color per row for a `Series`).

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# Get your plot settings
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({'f': np.random.randint(1,6,100)})
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame({'f': np.repeat(np.NaN,1000)}))
```

#### Code

```
df.f.value_counts().to_frame().sort_index().plot(kind='bar', legend=False)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this simplifies it a lot. Where would I read to find out what .value_counts() and .sort_index(), etc. are? Im new to plotting in python and im not sure exactly what tools I can use and rules and stuff like that.

Comment: Here is the documentation for [Series.value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and here is the documentation for [`DataFrame.sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html). They don't come with many examples, so I suggest you just look at what the output of `df.f.value_counts()` is, and then what happens when you do `df.f.value_counts().to_frame()` and then `df.f.value_counts().to_frame().sort_index()`, to see what each piece does separately.

Comment: and [`DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) though their tutorial on [Visualization](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html) is much more example oriented.